# Integral of $\int\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}$

Tags: integration

I was asked to find the following integral:

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}$$

What I tried to replace $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ with $u$ so that: $$du=\frac{dx}{x^3\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}} \Rightarrow du*x=\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}$$
And:$$x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-u^2}}$$
And we can replace:
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}=\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\arctan(u)+C=\arctan(\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}})+C$$
The problem is, when that result is derived we don't get the original expression. I just can't find my mistake, so some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $x\rightarrow 1/x$

Comment: Thanks, that indeed solved the integral. But my main interest was to find the mistake in my solution, since I can't find it and I will surely make the same mistake later...

Comment: @tired Were you too "tired" to post this as a solution?  (+1) for the comment.

Comment: Your solution should be $\text{arscin}(u)$ not $\arctan(u)$.

Comment: @Dr. MV in most cases i only post a solution if the problem poses some challenge to me, which wasn't the case here. Furhtermore the hint is good enough for finishing off this one quickly by the op himself

Comment: @tired I was trying and failing to make a play of words from your user name.

Comment: @Dr. MV i got the irony, no worries ;) Nevertheless i thought it is a good opportunity to explain my behaviour of commenting often and answering seldom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The substitution $u=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ is equivalent to $|x|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$.  For $x>1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{1-\frac1{x^2}}}\,dx&=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du\\\\
&=\arcsin(u)+C\\\\
&=\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}\right)+C\\\\
&=-\arcsin(1/x)+C'
\end{align}$$

where we used the identity $\arcsin(1/x)+\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}\right)=(\pi/2)\text{sgn}(x)=\pi/2$ when $x>1$.

One can proceed similarly for the case in which $x<-1$.

Comment: ridicolous downvote removed

Comment: @tired Thank you for neutralizing the down vote!

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $\text{u}=\frac{1}{x}$:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(x\right)=\int\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}\space\text{d}x=-\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\text{u}^2}}\space\text{d}\text{u}$$

---

Now, use:

$$\frac{\text{d}\arcsin\left(x\right)}{\text{d}x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

---

So, we get:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(x\right)=\text{C}-\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\text{C}-\text{arccsc}\left(x\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\dfrac1{x^2\sqrt{1-\dfrac1{x^2}}}=\dfrac{|x|}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

Set $\sqrt{x^2-1}=u\implies x^2=u^2+1$ and $x\ dx=u\ du$

Comment: Yeah I tried doing it with a different replacement and I succeeded... I just can't find the reason why what I tried failed, so it would help if you could find the mistake, thanks anyway.

Comment: @JonathanMartinez,  I want to learn my mistake :)

Comment: No, the left hand side is positive, the right hand side is negative for $x<0$, so they definitely can't be equal.

Comment: @egreg, Thanks for your observation.